# Neural network Hyper-parameters Optimization and Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am working on very large dataset in Keras with a single-output neural network. Upon a change in depth of the network, I observed some improvements in the performance of the model. Therefore, I wanted to perform ""A systematic"" research-wise hyper-parameter optimization now (hidden layers, activation functions, # neurons, epochs, batch size, etc.). However, I was told that GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV are not proper options since my dataset is large. I was wondering if any of you have experience in this regard or have feedback which may direct me to the right path.

Comment: GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV are used with classifiers like Random Forest and XGBoost and Logistic regression.   Use dropout to tune your keras network and activation using relu or tanh or LeakyRelu or sigmoid for your network.  Setup layers in your network. binary_crossentropy

Comment: Thank you. I meant if there any systematic approach that could be followed step by step since this is a research paper

Comment: you can use MLP classifier https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html   you can their use GridSearchCV to find the optimium parameters

Comment: What is your data set so I can test it in keras

Answer (score 0):

use a confusion matrix and heat map to measure performance accuracy of your network

```
Y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
Y_pred2=np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
Y_test2=np.argmax(Y_test, axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test2, Y_pred2)
sns.heatmap(cm)
plt.show()

print(classification_report(Y_test2, Y_pred2,target_names=label_names))
```

Comment: How can the confusion matrix help in a regression problem?

Comment: You uses the confusion matrix to measure the precision and recall of the neural network.  The network can be multi class categorical crossentropy